# Query Bootgrid - use a custom ID name

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

I am using http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com to generate my CRUD grids (I am thinking of using Datatables in the future, as Bootgrid does not appear to be maintained anymore for several years now).

I have a grid of entries where the "edit" link and "delete" link must not reference the same ID. Reason being: the item in the grid contains information from 2 tables `activity` and `activity_detail` and when I delete the entry, the `activity` and the `activity_detail` is deleted. That works fine. But when I want to click on `Edit` in my grid, I want to edit the `activity_detail` only.

My (simplified) data structure is:

```
ACTIVITY
`id`
`reference_id`

ACTIVITY_DETAIL
`id`
...additional detail fields...
```

The link between the two tables is ACTIVITY.reference_id = ACTVITY_DETAIL.reference_id

So - when deleting, I want to use ACTIVITY.id and when I edit, I want to use ACTIVITY_DETAIL.reference_id as the key.

Is this possible?